What can be done about input on Windows system not working as expected on MacBook (2015)?
I have a MacBook Air (2015) with 256 GB of storage, on which I installed Windows.
And because of the storage, I had to delete the system drive, and only now Windows is installed on it.
But unfortunately, right click on Windows, volume and f1 , f2 keys… it doesn't work.
What are the drivers that can be installed on the MacBook to make them work?

Why do you install Windows on a Mac?

I was more comfortable this way

Normally you would use the macOS Boot Camp Assistant application to download the drivers for your Mac. To ensure the latest release of drivers is downloaded, you would need to run the Boot Camp Assistant application from the latest version of macOS available for your Mac. You also need to run this application from your Mac, because a different model/year Mac may use a different set of drivers.
You can use third party software to download the drivers from Windows. For example, the Brigadier application can be used. This application can have a flaw where the release of drivers downloaded is not the latest version. Since Apple only issued one release of drivers for your Mac, this flaw will not be an issue in your case.

Download and install 7-Zip. Brigadier requires the use of 7-Zip. The latest release of 7-Zip installer for Windows can be downloaded from here. After downloading, run the download application to install 7-Zip. If you wish, you can uninstall 7-Zip after you are finished downloading the drivers.
Download and execute Brigadier. The latest release of Brigadier.exe can be downloaded from here. After downloading, open a Windows Command Prompt window and execute the following commands.
cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
brigadier


Install the drivers.
cd /d "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\BootCamp-041-98143\BootCamp"
Setup

When finished, you can delete the BootCamp-041-98143 folder.
Download any driver updates from Apple. Run the Apple Software Update application to see if any driver updates exist for your Mac. Note that if the Apple Software Update application has updates for itself, then download and install those updates before downloading and installing other updates.
Download any driver updates from Microsoft. Run Windows Update to see if any optional driver updates exist.

